# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' when attempting to retrieve Table Data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

People have asked similar questions like this 100 times before but none of the solutions are working to fix my issue! I have created a html doc that I am hosting off github that has a table on it! The table is going to be used to store a Players Username, Password and UserID. The webscraping is going good on a whole other project I am working on but it is not working here!

Down below I have put the Python script that is webscraping the website I have created!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def getData():
    url = 'https://galaxy-indie-studio.github.io/Galaxy-Indie-Studio-Website/database.html'
    html_url = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_url, "lxml")

    database = soup.find_all('tr', class_="Player")

    for Players in database:
        username = Players.find('td', class_="Username").text 
        password = Players.find('td', class_="Password").text
        userID = Players.find('td', class_="UserID").text

        print(f"Username in database {username}")
        print(f"Password in database {password}")
        print(f"UserID in database {userID}")
```

If I leave the .text on the end of any of the variables I recieve AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute. If I remove the .text it returns as None, It's the same for username, password and userID

Down below I have put in the code that I have used so far for the website that i am using to store the table on!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Player Database</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border = 4px, bgcolor="black", width= 100%> 
            <tr>
                <th width="150" height="20" bgcolor="lightgray">Username</th>
                <th width="150" height="20" bgcolor="lightgray">Password</th>
                <th width="150" height="20" bgcolor="lightgray">UserID</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="Player", width="150" height="20">
                <td align="center" bgcolor="lightgray",class="Username">BigTall12</td>
                <td align = "center" bgcolor="lightgray",class="Password"></td>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="lightgray",class="UserID"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="Player",width="150" height="20">
                <td align="center" bgcolor="lightgray",class="Username"></td>
                <td align = "center" bgcolor="lightgray",class="Password"></td>
                <td align = "center" bgcolor="lightgray",class="UserID"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="Player",width="150" height="20">
                <td align="center" bgcolor="lightgray",class="Username"></td>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="lightgray",class="Password"></td>
                <td align="center"bgcolor="lightgray",class="UserID"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="Player",width="150" height="20">
                <td align="center" bgcolor="lightgray",class="Username"></td>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="lightgray",class="Password"></td>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="lightgray",class="UserID"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you don't have a `class` attribute in the `<td>` tags. You do have a `,class` attribute though, and bs4 won't recognise that.

So what I'm saying is, your html is wrong. Get rid of those commas before the class attributes in your source html.

For example:

```
`<td align="center" bgcolor="lightgray",class="Username">BigTall12</td>`
```

should be

```
`<td align="center" bgcolor="lightgray" class="Username">BigTall12</td>`
```

Or, fix it once you read in the html:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getData():
    url = 'https://galaxy-indie-studio.github.io/Galaxy-Indie-Studio-Website/database.html'
    html_url = requests.get(url).text
    html_url = html_url.replace(',class', ' class')
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_url, "lxml")

    database = soup.find_all('tr', class_="Player")

    for Players in database:
        username = Players.find('td', class_="Username").text 
        password = Players.find('td', class_="Password").text
        userID = Players.find('td', class_="UserID").text

        print(f"Username in database {username}")
        print(f"Password in database {password}")
        print(f"UserID in database {userID}")
        
        
getData()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't realize how I didn't catch that. Sometimes it is just useful to have a second set of eye's I guess. Again thank you very much for your help and have a great day/night